# Windows Vista computer won't power on when connected to router

Tags: router, windows-vista, power-management

In all of my years of supporting PCs, I have never seen this. Here's hoping y'all have an idea.

My client has a home PC running Windows Vista (long story as to why he hasn't upgraded). He has a `Linksys WRTG54 v6` router directly connected to it running 1.00.9v firmware. The light on the router that matches the port the computer is connected to stays on even when the machine is shut down. I have not yet checked whether WoL is turned on, but let's assume yes.

When he wakes up in the morning, that light on the router is no longer on. When he tries to turn on the computer, it won't budge. If he unplugs the router and tries to turn on the computer, it works. Once he plugs the router back in, it continues to work and he can access the internet. Even shutting the machine off, waiting, and turning it back on with the router connected and plugged in works. Something seems to be happening in the evening that's borking it. This all started about three days ago.

My guess here is that the router is flooding the Ethernet adapter with traffic, which is somehow preventing the machine from starting or forcing it to completely shutdown all attempts to turn it on until the connection is severed. But, honestly, I have no idea how the heck to troubleshoot this. The Windows event logs are, of course, no help because the machine is shut off during the evening. I'm not at the client's home now and it was too late before I realized I didn't look at the router logs.

Have any of you every experienced this? Any specific ideas on what may be happening and how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is a power issue / short circuit somewhere. Have you tried different ports on the router ? I had a 5 port switch years ago where a couple of the ports must have shorted at times or something, and the computer would freeze whenever the ports shorted.

Comment: That is ridiculously crazy. I'll give that a shot, thanks!